# MVC3 Ajax call to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there anyway to submit a form but have it remain on the page?

Right now I'm displaying a table of objects, but each row has an editable value with each row in its own Ajax form but when I click the update button it goes to the method alright but the whole page changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there anyway to submit a form but have it remain on the page?

Of course, you could use AJAX:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... some form input fields

    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

and then unobtrusively AJAXify this form in a separate file:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: handle the results of the AJAX call
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and to avoid writing all this javascript code you may take a look at the excellent [jquery.form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

```
$(function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        // TODO: handle the results of the AJAX call
    });
});
```

Another alternative is to use the ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm helper:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success" }))
{
    ... some form input fields

    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

and then have a success handler in javascript:

```
function success(result) {
    // TODO: handle the results of the AJAX call
}
```

you will also need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in addition to `jquery` to your page if you want to use the `Ajax.*` helpers.

Comment: Actually, just needed to add the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script, but thanks so much for your help. I have been pulling my hair out(or whats left of it).